# React Native (Android Native Module): Get access to ReactContext in another Class?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I want to call a method in MyCustomModuleClass extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule from another Class

> MyCustomModule.java

```
public class MyCustomModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private ReactContext mReactContext;

  public MyCustomModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    mReactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "CustomModule";
  }


    private void sendEvent(String eventName, Object params) {
        mReactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(eventName, params);
    }    
}
```

I'm trying this..

> OtherClass.java

```
public class OtherClass extends AnotherClass {

    @Override
    protected void eventOccurred(Context context) {
        MyCustomModule RNC = new MyCustomModule(?);//-> Can't call without ReactContext
        RNC.sendEvent("CustomEvent", ObjectData); 
    }   
}
```

Sorry, I know nothing about java, could any one please help me out?

Is there any way I can get ReactContext in OtherClass?

Comment: It does not look like your calling a valid constructor on MyCustomModule. Maybe thats just a typo you made when trying to create a simple example. I don't see why you could not do that. Just try it.

Comment: Yes, I was doing it all wrong. Let me update my question.

Comment: I solved my problem by another way, using LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: @antihate - Would you mind sharing your solution? This problem is driving me nuts..

Comment: this question got more feed back in the issues: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5846

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I did it in a `FirebaseMessagingService` extended class.

```
public class MyPushListener extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(JSONObject message, JSONObject content){

    MainApplication application = (MainApplication) this.getApplication();

    ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost = application.getReactNativeHost();
    ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager();
    ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();

    if (reactContext != null) {
      WritableNativeArray params = new WritableNativeArray();
      params.pushString(message.toString());
      reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
          .emit("EVENT_HAS_TRIGGERED", params);
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5846#issuecomment-385230183)

Comment: I also did this but with RN 0.71.8 I see this warning  for getCurrentReactContext();`
This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope`